# What is the difference between using "dictA.get('a') or dictB.get('a')" versus a nested if?

Tags: python

Is there a difference between using `or` instead of a nested `if` if you want to test a few conditions, but default to the last `or`?

For instance, instead of writing:

```
DEFAULT = {'a': 'default'}

a = request.args.get('a')
if not a:
    a = request.cookies.get('a')
    if not a:
        a = DEFAULT['a']
```

write this:

```
a = request.args.get('a') or request.cookies.get('a') or DEFAULT['a']
```

since `or` will return the first truthy argument or the value of the last argument evaluated if none of the earlier arguments were true.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a strict definition what "pythonic" is — while it's common to agree that some things are pythonic or not, I think this one isn't one where you can give a definite answer. I'd say — it's okay to do this if you don't impact the code readability (and, personally, I think the "or" form looks better).

Comment: I've tried to edit this to make it a bit less subjective; I *do* think there's a good question here, inasmuch as the semantics aren't identical.

Comment: @Charles Duffy: Yes, I also thought of pointing out about falsey values (but didn't because both versions handle them similarly and don't have explicit `is not None`). With your edit, I think the question is good.

Comment: I would say the latter is extremely Pythonic. [Flat is better than nested.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good edits. Thanks for the discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short form

Any of these can be a reasonable choice so long as you've thought carefully about whether you want any falsey values to be represented. Python values terseness and readability, so shorter, less-nested code is valued -- so absent a compelling contrary reason, I would suggest going with either the nested-`or` approach or the `get()`-default approach.

That said, take the semantics of all available options in mind:

---

#### Nested `if` approach

The exact nested `if` proposed in the question (using `if not a:`) has no advantages over the `or` line, but consider instead the following:

```
a = request.args.get('a')
if a is None:
    a = request.cookies.get('a')
    if a is None:
        a = DEFAULT['a']
```

This treats only `None` as a lookup failure (though it does so even in the event of a `None` genuinely existing in the data), rather than treating a successful lookup of a falsey non-`None` value (`0`, `''`, `False`, etc) as a case wherein we still need to fall back.

---

#### Chained `or` approach

With chained `or`s, all falsey values are treated as lookup failures. Thus:

```
request.args = {'a': None}
a = request.args.get('a') or request.cookies.get('a') or DEFAULT['a']
```

...will use the result from `request.cookies` or `DEFAULT`, despite `request.args` having an explicit and valid value.

---

#### `a.get(x, b.get(y, ...))` approach

...which is to say:

```
a = request.args.get('a', request.cookies.get('a', DEFAULT.get('a')))
```

Using the `default=` parameter to `dict.get()`, one can *explicitly* provide a default for each lookup.

The advantage of this is that the result of the first lookup to succeed will be used, **even if the result of that lookup is `None`**.

The disadvantage is that parameter evaluation for function calls is always non-lazy, so all three lookups will always take place.